# Is the subject complement a noun or an adjective here?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, subject-complement

It's well-known that a *subject complement* can be a noun or an adjective. It's not hard to make out what part of speech the *subject complement* belongs to— For example, in *He is a pilot* and *She is beautiful*, it's easy to say that the *subject complement* is a noun and an adjective, respectively.

But is this always the case? What about the sentence—

*Outside is a hawker.*

The subject of the sentence is *hawker* and it's apparent that *outside* couldn't be a description of the hawker, and so it can't be a noun. The possibility of its being an adjective is also ruled out because it doesn't "modify" *hawker* in any way.

Could it be that the sentence is actually an abbreviated version of *On the outside is a hawker*?

This seems to make sense because here the NP *the outside* could be serving as the object of the preposition *on.*

Is that right? Or am I confusing things here?

Comment: It's a case of subject-dependent inversion. The preposition phrase "outside" has been preposed to the front of the clause and the subject "a hawker" has been postposed to final position where it receives greater phonological prominence. "Outside" is of course a complement of "be". Does that help?

Comment: @BillJ— Thank you but my question is _since complements of the *be* verb are either adjectives or nouns, what's *outside* here in that capacity, i.e., is it an adjective or a noun? It doesn't seem to be either as I have mentioned that in the question itself. Maybe this is again a misunderstanding of grammar basics in the modern light, I don't know.

Comment: Complements of "be" are most often nouns and adjectives, but they may also be prepositions like "outside", as in your example (and also for example in _We are in your debt_) and even adverbs like "slowly", as in _The only way to cook it is **slowly**_. I did say in my previous comment that "outside" is a complement of "be".

Comment: That clinches it! Actually now that you have answered it, it seems rather obvious to me. Poor research from my part in that I could have hit upon those _preposition/ adverb as complement_ constructions myself. But thank you very much! @BillJ And indeed you said in your previous comment that _outside is a complement of **be**_, but i was still preoccupied with the false notion that only adjectives and nouns are complements of _be._ I thought it was a case of preposition omission like _[on the] Outside is a hawker_, where the noun _outside_ was complement of the preposition _on._

Comment: @BillJ— I was going to ask you _what if I substituted **there** in place of **outside** in my sentence_, but thought better of it. I knew it would amount to taking a detour and basically arriving at the same basic question— which centers around the difference in perspectives of modern and traditional approaches. So I did a little research (googling basically)— reading @Astralbee's answer further necessitated it— and came across this (link below). I think I should connect the dots myself from here onwards.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182975/is-there-an-adverb-or-a-preposition-or-something-else-entirely%23:~:text%3DA%2520preposition%2520occurs%2520before%2520a,called%2520an%2520adverbial%2520demonstrative%2520pronoun.&ved=2ahUKEwiB9dvnhuvtAhWKfH0KHaEFBugQFjABegQIAhAE&usg=AOvVaw23XvraIMwKCKbcRqe3mQ4V&cshid=1608965327261

Comment: @First, I don't agree with the answer in the link you provided. Whatever, I think you're looking for something that isn't there. Your very simple example has subject-dependent inversion, and consists of C-V-S. The basic version is "Outside is a hawker", where the NP "a hawker" has been placed in final position where it receives greater phonological prominence. It could not be simpler!

Comment: @BillJ— The answer to this question (as provided below) says _outside_ is an adverb, while you have maintain it's a preposition. So just to cross-check which of these two versions made more sense, I substituted a familiar *adverb of place* (there) for *outside.* And there's actually this question regarding the POS *there* belongs to (as the link says.) So I don't see how it isn't germane to the discussion at hand. *subject- dependent inversion* isn't my main concern here.

Comment: Your question is about 'subject complement - noun or adjective?'. I've given you a comprehensive answer to that question. What more do you want?

Comment: @BillJ— Indeed you have and for that I am thankful to you, Sir! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subject complement:

1. adds information about the subject
2. usually comes after linking verbs

As you rightly said, 'the hawker' is the subject in your example. This could also be written as:

> A hawker is outside.

Written this way, 'outside' adds information (location) about the subject. A preposition shows the relative positioning between two things, so really this is substituting for '*outside the house*'.

As a rule of thumb, expressions of place and time go at the *end* of a sentence (as in my re-written example). They only go at the beginning of a sentence *if they are not the main focus* in the sentence. By this rule, 'outside is a hawker' is not correct.

'Outside, there is a hawker' sounds a little better, but is not idiomatic with the present tense. If you were telling someone that a hawker was outside the house *right now* it seems to me the location would be pretty important and so should follow the rule that it goes at the end of the sentence.

If you were writing in the *past tense*, then it is more common to see the placement first, for example:

> It was warm inside the house. Outside, the snow fell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer. Two quick questions— 1) why do you rule out the possibility of _outside_ being a _preposition instead of an adverb_, which acts as the complement of _be?_ 2) Doesn't _inversion_ allow for constructions like _outside is [NP]_? Basically, what does it mean to say _doesn't sound quite right_? — do you mean it's not idiomatic, while still being grammatically correct or what? @Astralbee

Comment: @User40475 1) Fair point - it probably *is* acting as a preposition. A preposition shows the relative positioning between TWO things, and your sentence only mentions one - the hawker. However, 'outside' is substituting for 'outside the house', which as a phrase could still be a subject complement. 2) It's not really inversion... that's where you can say "John is my teacher" or "my teacher is John" because they are the same thing. In that example, "is" means "equals". "A hawker is outside" doesn't mean "outside" and "hawker" are the same thing.

Comment: Thank you once again. But may I now ask why you switched from _adverb_ to _preposition_, when there isn't apparently anything wrong with _outside_ being an adverb in the sentence? @Astralbee

Comment: @User40475 I've correct my answer, I was wrong to call the word an adverb. However, while the word is a preposition it forms part of an *adverbial phrase*. Your question is about subject complements and these are never just a preposition alone. I've explained in my answer that 'outside' implies 'outside *the house*'.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you! :)

Comment: @User40475 "Outside" is a preposition phrase consisting of the preposition "outside" alone. The PP serves not as an adverbial phrase but as complement of "be". Trad grammar tends to classify "outside" as a prep when it has an NP complement and as an adverb when it has no complement. But in modern grammar the presence or absence of a complement has no bearing on the classification of "outside" as a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ— Perfect! This bit on the difference in perspectives of old and new approach obviates need for any further discussion.